# when I trying to run my spring application on the server (tomcat) this error message rises:

Tags: spring, tomcat

> console

**ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/C:/Users/ismailalabou/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.40/wtpwebapps/EBoutiqueV3/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml];**

> /EBoutiqueV3/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    
    <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sid_eboutique"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
        <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_BOUTIQUE"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    
    <bean id="dao" class="org.sid.eboutique.dao.BoutiqueDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="metier" class="org.sid.eboutique.metier.BoutiqueMetierImpl">
        <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <s:http>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/adminProd/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN_PROD"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/adminCat/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN_CAT"/>
        <s:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/adminProd/index"
        authentication-failure-url="/login" />
        <s:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </s:http>
    <s:authentication-manager>
        <s:authentication-provider>
        <s:password-encoder hash="md5"></s:password-encoder>
        <s:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="datasource"
        users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, r.roleName from users u, role r
        where u.id_user = r.id_user and u.username =? " />
        </s:authentication-provider>
    </s:authentication-manager> 
    <!-- Tiles View Resolver Configuration -->
    <bean id="tilesViewresolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.sid">
        <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="org.sid.*" />
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

> /EBoutiqueV3/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
  
  <persistence-unit name="UP_BOUTIQUE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Could you please add more details?

Comment: @prostýčlověk I added the 2 files associated with the error, as far as I know.